# Odd TLS Error when using curl on origin server x.509

Tags: networking, ssl, security, certificate, curl

I am hoping someone can help explain what is happening in this situation..

As of now, I have a domain from google domains and I am using cloudflare for my DNS management. I am not using any TLS/SSL features from cloudflare, universal SSL is off, and not proxying my DNS requests either. I use caddy as my reverse proxy on my server and I am using the built-in acme client that gets certificates from letsencrypt. I am getting certificates fine and my external sites are all showing the cert being used which is the cert located on my server. However, when I run a `curl` command on my server over HTTPS, I get this strange behaviour:

To explain more, I am trying to send a curl request to my gotify server/instance. Here is the output when I use the gotify cli command `gotify init` then I type in my domain with https:// and receive this output (this happens for all of my domains (when I run the basic curl commands below after the gotify command), but just using gotify cli as an example of where the error originates from):

```
x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match gotify.mydomain.com
```

So, I run these curl commands to figure out what is happening.

Command: `curl -v https://gotify.mydomain.com`
Output:

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

My CApath literally has all of the certs from the ca-certificates package. And my external sites are using my cert, but my server is having issues and I don't know why.

When I run this command `curl -v --insecure https://gotify.mydomain.com` I get even stranger results:
Output:

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CN; ST=TW; L=TB; O=ASKEY; OU=ROUTER; CN=askey.com; emailAddress=askey@askey.com
*  start date: Jan  8 18:43:23 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  7 18:43:23 2025 GMT
*  issuer: C=CN; ST=TW; L=TB; O=ASKEY; OU=ROUTER; CN=askey.com; emailAddress=askey@askey.com
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: gotify.mydomain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: /1.2.4/login.html
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sun, 24 Apr 2022 13:51:04 GMT
< Server: lighttpd/1.4.38
<
* Connection #0 to host gotify.mydomain.com left intact
```

Have absolutely no idea where this "askey" cert even came from. It is nowhere located on my server AFAIK. I am beyond confused. I am located in Taiwan, so the TW code might make a little sense. I didn't even have access to my server remotely on Jan 8th, so I don't know what happened.

When I see this `Location: /1.2.4/login.html` this makes me think something is going on with my router. Because that is the path for my router admin login page.

Comment: It is somewhat common for wireless hotspots to [force you to complete some action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) by meddling with any and all your connections until you comply. Your [browser might know](http://detectportal.firefox.com/canonical.html) how to automatically deal with this.

Comment: Askey is a taiwanese producer of routers. What you show indicates a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) of such a router which you need to pass before you can access the internet.

Comment: But I am confused, my origin sever is located in the US. The error should have nothing to do with my client connections right? I just SSH into my machine and run these commands. I will look into the captive portal I suppose

Comment: I understand what is happening now. Basically, I am trying to access my external/public IP (through my domain that points to my external IP/route) internally on the same network where my server is, which won't work afaik. I will need to setup dnsmasq or something to do the rewriting.